# Connect to delta table in hdfs using python without using Pyspark

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, delta-lake, pyarrow, delta-rs

I have a delta table in hdfs stored as a hive table. I need to connect to the table and load the latest version of the table. I was able to connect to hdfs using pyarrow library. But it is loading entire versions on the hdfs. Here is my code

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.fs as fs
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host=ip,port=port)
dt = fs.read_parquet('/path/to/file/in/hdfs')
dt.to_pandas()
```

But here I am getting entire historical data in the table. Is there an option to specify that I am loading a delta table in pyarrow?

Another approach I tried is using deltalake library. Here I was not able to connect to a hdfs location. Please check the code below

```
from deltalake import DeltaTable
table_path_hdfs ="hdfs://ip:port/path/to/file/in/hdfs"
dt = DeltaTable(table_path_hdfs)
```

*While running the code I am getting error **deltalake.PyDeltaTableError: Delta-rs must be build with feature 'hdfs' to support loading from: hdfs://**

Is there way we can load delta-rs with hdfs support?

Can anybody suggest any other libraries for this?

Comment: I'm confused. You want to read an HDFS file without having to build HDFS support in your library?

Comment: No basically I need to know if there is a way to read delta table stored in hdfs using python. In case delta-rs doesn't support hdfs is there any other libraries we can use?

Comment: Pyspark or Pyflink could be used. But delta-rs will work, you just need to compile with hdfs support first